# Ask recommend ways that Lua cowork with C/C++?

Tags: c, lua

Recently I learned Lua, we need it to co-work with existed C code(HTTP server).

From Lua books, we know that there maybe to way to make them co-working:

- From Lua, you can wrap C code in share library(`xxx.so`) that Lua use `require` to import them.
- From C, you can use existed Lua API to operate on `lua_state`, it's some trick but it works well.

I adopt both of them and everything seems great, by using Lua we can save a lot of time to implement our business logic. But I'm quite nervous about current architecture, although there was no serious problem in it, I always worried about it, if there was some thing happened, for example, serious performance bottleneck, memory related and so on.

Is anyone got rich experience in this, please give some some advice. Thanks.

Comment: need to edit your question,  its not really clear what you are trying to ask.  The title asks one thing, the content seems to ask something else

Comment: About memory - you don't need to worry cause of garbage collector. Of course unless you are not using your own reference counting mechanisms or etc - with bugs in that mechanisms you can introduce memory leaks quite simple. I also remember that bad operating on lua stack can introduce some errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua is designed to work well with both C and C++. The C API is meant for that.

You don't need to create and use shared libraries to extend Lua. It is the easiest way to extend the standard command line interpreter but it should be easy (if not easier) to link static C libraries for Lua in your own application.

If you want to see some examples of C libraries for Lua, see [mine](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/). There are many others.